# Soap Client works in console mode, but not as a NUnit test

Tags: c#, nunit, soap-client

This soap client works if its run as a console, but as a test (nunit) doesn't. the error in the second case is: " Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

```
     [TestFixture]
    public class BasicTests
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var service = new ServiceReference2.GatewaySoapClient())
            {
                var result = service.GetFileStatus("bla", "bla", false);
            }
        }

        [TestCase]
        public void FileInfoTest()
        {

            using (var service = new ServiceReference2.GatewaySoapClient())
            {
                var result = service.GetFileStatus("bla", "bla", false);
            }
        }
}
```

F5 and works, Debug test fail. A mystery

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` are different in both cases, I have to force it in test mode with:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
using (var service = new ServiceReference2.GatewaySoapClient())
{
    var result = service.GetFileStatus("bla", "bla", false);
}
```

Very hard issue to find. Hope this post can help someone else. Note: It happens too calling it inside web application.